# Simultaneous navigation with maps and streetview with the V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

i'm trying to figure out the code shown of this page with the V2 https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/examples/streetview-data?hl=es for the V3 of googlemaps but i can't refresh the position of the orange icon when navigating with the streetview.... any ideas?

Another point... how can i get the actual lat long when navigating on both views?

Here's some code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<title>Zone -</title>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&sensor=false">
</script>
<script>   

$(function(){
function sleep(milliseconds) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
      if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
        break;
      }
    }
}

initialize();
});


var map;
var myPano;   
var panoClient;
var nextPanoId;
var panorama;  
function initialize() {
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }

      var fenwayPark = new google.maps.LatLng(42.345573,-71.098326);
    var fenwayPOV = {yaw:370.64659986187695,pitch:-20};

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    panoClient = new google.maps.StreetViewService();      
      //map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
      map.setCenter(fenwayPark, 15);
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(overlay, latlng) {
        // latlng will be null if the info window has been clicked.
        if (latlng) {
          panoClient.getNearestPanorama(latlng, showPanoData);
        }
      });

      var panoramaOptions = {
              position: fenwayPark,
              pov: {                  
                heading: 34,
                pitch: -20
              }
            };
      myPano = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById("pano"),panoramaOptions);
      //map.setStreetView(myPano);
      myPano.setPano(fenwayPark, fenwayPOV);

      google.maps.event.addListener(myPano, "error", handleNoFlash);  
      panoClient.getPanoramaByLocation(fenwayPark, 50, processSVData);
      //myPano.setStreetView(myPano);
}


function processSVData(data, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: data.location.latLng,
          map: map,
          title: data.location.description
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

          var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
          // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID
          myPano.setPano(markerPanoID);
          myPano.setPov({
            heading: 270,
            pitch: 0,
            zoom: 1
          });
          myPano.setVisible(true);
        });
      }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you look at [the equivalent example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) in the [documentation for Streetview for v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview)?

Comment: Nope, google it for hours but did not get this page :). Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes it is more useful to read the documentation than search the web.